# How to run a subquery to split a table into two groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I've got a table called `spending` (actually in BigQuery, though I don't think that's necessarily relevant for this question) that is about 2.9GB and 19 million rows.

The data structure is like this:

```
product,org,spend,to_include,proportion_overseas
----------------------------------
SK001,03V,"Yes",0.1
SK002,03V,2.4,"Yes",0.1
SK001,O3T,66.1,"No",0.47
SK002,03T,87.1,"No",0.47
SK001,04C,16.1,"Yes",0
SK002,04C,27.1,"Yes",0
...
```

For info, it is slightly denormalised, in that `to_include` and `proportion_overseas` are actually properties of each organisation.

Now I want to work out, for each product:

- the total amount that all organisations with no overseas spending spent on that product, and
- the total amount that all organisations with non-zero overseas spending spent on that product.

I also only want to include in this calculation only rows where `to_include='Yes'`.

I'm not sure what the best approach to do this is in SQL. I don't mind whether I end up with two tables, or one.

I know how to get all spending by code, for all relevant rows:

```
SELECT product, SUM(spend) 
FROM spending 
WHERE to_include='Yes'
GROUP BY product;
```

But what I don't know is how to split each row into two groups: one group where `proportion_overseas=0` and one group where `proportion_overseas>0`.

I don't think 'subquery' is the right term, so I don't really know what to Google for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product, SUM(spend),
       SUM(CASE WHEN proportion_overseas = 0 THEN spend ELSE 0 END) as not_overseas,
       SUM(CASE WHEN proportion_overseas > 0 THEN spend ELSE 0 END) as overseas
FROM spending 
WHERE to_include='Yes'
GROUP BY product;
```